# Laravel Telescope didn't find anything

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

Telescope shows "We couldn't find anything" error while loading telescope/requests. I get this empty page instead of my api listing. I'm using mongodb

The console is showing this

```
{"entries":[],"status":"enabled"}
```

[image]
laravel log is showing

> local.ERROR: $documents is empty {"exception":"[object]
>   (MongoDB\Exception\InvalidArgumentException(code: 0):

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, the issue it's in the in the method constructor of the file vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/InsertMany.php, this is my case